# jsTree shows only the last root node when nodes are added using create_node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have created a jsTree like

```
$('.containerTree').jstree({
    "core": {
        "check_callback": true,
        "data": ["Root"]
    }
});
```

Adding scripts:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.9/jstree.min.js"></script>
```

So, I wanted to created and showing a list of root nodes with childs. For that I use "create_node" function in loop:

```js
for (var iteration = 0; iteration < 10; iteration++) {
       var newNodes= $(".containerTree").jstree("create_node",null,"root"+iteration, "last", function (node) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            var newDataChild = {
                                "text": "child" + i,
                                "id": "child" + i
                            };
                            tree.create_node(node, newDataChild, "last", function (newChild) {
                            });
            }         
});
```

I expected to see result like this:

```
Root1
  ----child1
 ...
RootN
  ----child1
  ..........
```

As a result nodes are created, but showing only the last root node. Who can explain why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix two issues:

1. `tree.create_node(...` - tree variable wasn't defined anywhere
2. `.create_node` - better use same approach as first time

So the correct code would look like below. Check demo - [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/1vygwfot/)

```
var $tree = $(".containerTree");
for (var iteration = 0; iteration < 10; iteration++) {
    $tree.jstree("create_node",null,"root"+iteration, "last", function (node) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          var newDataChild = {
            "text": "child" + i,
            "id": "child" + i
          };
         $tree.jstree("create_node", node, newDataChild, "last");
        }         
    });
}
```